# Creating a new realm in keycloak by using exported realm json file in keycloak

Tags: node.js, json, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

Hi I have a requirement where i have to create a realm in keycloak using a rest api.

Below are the steps that i have done so far,

1. called a api `${process.env.KEYCLOAK_BASEURL}/admin/realms` , passed the below body data

```
{
  "id": "req.body.realmId",
  "realm": "req.body.realmId",
  "displayName": "req.body.realmName",
  "defaultSignatureAlgorithm": "RS256",
  "revokeRefreshToken": false,
  "refreshTokenMaxReuse": 0,
  "accessTokenLifespan": 3600,
  "accessTokenLifespanForImplicitFlow": 1200,
  "ssoSessionIdleTimeout": 1800,
  "ssoSessionMaxLifespan": 36000,
  "ssoSessionIdleTimeoutRememberMe": 0,
  "ssoSessionMaxLifespanRememberMe": 0,
  "offlineSessionIdleTimeout": 2592000,
  "offlineSessionMaxLifespanEnabled": false,
  "offlineSessionMaxLifespan": 5184000,
  "clientSessionIdleTimeout": 0,
  "clientSessionMaxLifespan": 0,
  "clientOfflineSessionIdleTimeout": 0,
  "clientOfflineSessionMaxLifespan": 0,
  "accessCodeLifespan": 60,
  "accessCodeLifespanUserAction": 300,
  "accessCodeLifespanLogin": 1800,
  "actionTokenGeneratedByAdminLifespan": 43200,
  "actionTokenGeneratedByUserLifespan": 300,
  "oauth2DeviceCodeLifespan": 600,
  "oauth2DevicePollingInterval": 5,
  "enabled": true,
  "sslRequired": "external",
  "registrationAllowed": false,
  "registrationEmailAsUsername": true,
  "rememberMe": false,
  "verifyEmail": false,
  "loginWithEmailAllowed": true,
  "duplicateEmailsAllowed": false,
  "resetPasswordAllowed": true,
  "editUsernameAllowed": false,
  "bruteForceProtected": false,
  "permanentLockout": false,
  "maxFailureWaitSeconds": 900,
  "minimumQuickLoginWaitSeconds": 60,
  "waitIncrementSeconds": 60,
  "quickLoginCheckMilliSeconds": 1000,
  "maxDeltaTimeSeconds": 43200,
  "failureFactor": 30
}
```

This is creating a realm successfully.

My requirement here is to modify a exisiting realm exported json(with all mappers , roles and clients
) with just the new realmId and name and create a new realm.

I tried to export a json and replace the name and id but it threw mw a error stating

```
{ errorMessage: 'Conflict detected. See logs for details' }
```

When I looked into the json i saw that there are id's in the mappers and roles. Can I randomly generate a guuid and replace or is there any other way? Kindly guide